# gtk+ hiding menubar disables all keyboard shortcuts

Tags: c, gtk

I want to hide the menubar in my gtk+ text editor.  Thought that would be a simple matter of `gtk_widget_hide(menubar)`, but when I do that I loose all keyboard shortcuts.  How do you hide the menubar and keep the accelerator functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Hidden widgets do not respond to key events afaik.

A possible solution is to install a [AcceleratorGroup](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Keyboard-Accelerators.html) for your whole application instead.

You could also try to hide all items of the menu-bar (untested).